Blazor Cant load image, has been blocked by CORS policy, even tho i allowed any header any origin
I have an application where a js script inside has to put markers on a map, this icon comes from a folder on my api, any other image that is loaded inside my blazor load properly but when i load the image from my Js it says cant load resource cause of CORS.
My js code
addMarkerToGroup(group, { lat: partner.lat, lng: partner.long }, `${partner.id}`, new H.map.Icon(partner.icon));

My api program.cs
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());


Does anyone know how i can fix this issue.
Thank you
An desperate student
Load an image from my api when cors is anabled,
doesnt load and says cors blocks it

Welcome to Stack Overflow, but please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question accordingly.
